# Rules for space when using \mathrm{}

Tags: math-mode, spacing, mathrm

I am using auto-generated Latex code from CAS system.  It uses `\mathrm{ln}` and `{\mathrm e}`.

The problem is the spacing between this and the letter before it, compared to when no `\mathrm` is used.  The space is lost in the case with `\mathrm{ln}`

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\mleftright

\begin{document}
\[
4 {\mathrm e}^{3 x}+3 \mathrm{ln}\left(x \right)
\]
                      
\[
4 e^{3 x}+3 \ln\left(x \right)
\]                                                                                                              
\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex, gives

[image]

I prefer the second one. The space before `\mathrm e` has not changed. But the space before `\mathrm{ln}` was lost.

Why is that? Is it then not approrpiate to use `mathrm` for `ln`?

TL 2020

Comment: Expected>: \mathrm{.ln}˙is just two variables, but you like to rite math operator (which care between other also for space around it), So, instead of `3 + \mathrm{ln}\left(x \right)` you should always use `3 \ln(x)`

Comment: "Auto-generated Latex code"? Are you able to change the output to print `\ln` instead of `\mathrm{ln}`? If not, are you able to insert content within the preamble so one could possibly correct this programmatically?

Comment: @Werner  I can;t change the output of the Latex. I can ask the company that produced this latex to fix this and remove the mathrm. The Latex is generated automatically when given a math expression and users have no directly control on this. But they have good support and I am sure now I confirmed this is not optimal, they will correct it.

Comment: @Nasser: If you have access to the preamble, or inputting some alternative code, [here is an option](https://pastebin.com/raw/KJt7xGP2).

Comment: @Werner yes, I can add anything I want to preamble. I trying your code, but get an error that `Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \NewCommandCopy`. I am using lualatex to compile with. And thanks for the fix. I could use it until they fix the generated Latex code. This is the first time I see `\NewCommandCopy` Is this new command? I am using TL 2020 on Linux

Comment: @Nasser: It forms part of the Oct 2020 LaTeX update (see [LaTeX News
Issue 32](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews32.pdf), p 4). Alternatively, add `\usepackage{letltxmacro}` and then use `\LetLtxMacro\oldmathrm\mathrm`.

Comment: @Werner I see. OK, I will update My TL now then, I have not updated it for few months, that is why. Thank you.

Comment: @Werner I updated to latest TL. I get new error. So I will try the alternative you posted above.   FYI, the new error is `lualatex foo3.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
(./foo3.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\mathrm  #1->\ifnum \pdfstrcmp
                               {#1}{ln}=0 \ln \else \oldmathrm {#1} \fi
l.22 4 {\mathrm e
               }^{3 x}+3 \mathrm{ln}\left(x \right)
?`

Comment: @Werner hummm. I must be doing something wrong
`\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro} 
\LetLtxMacro\oldmathrm\mathrm

\begin{document}

So, $3\ln(x)$ and $3\mathrm{ln}(x)$ show differently.
\end{document}`
Compiled with lualatex gives same error `! Undefined control sequence.
\mathrm  #1->\ifnum \pdfstrcmp`

Comment: @Nasser: Ahh, forgot you're using LuaLaTeX. You also need `\usepackage{pdftexcmds}` since I used `\pdfstrcmp`. `\pdfstrcmp` was just to perform a string comparison between the argument supplied to `\mathrm` and `ln`. If it matches, call `\ln`, otherwise call `\oldmathrm` (the original `\mathrm` which was copied into `\oldmathrm` via `\LetLtxMacro` or `\NewCommandCopy`).

Comment: @Werner if you wish and have time, may be you could post this as answer. This way I do not make mistakes trying to understand what to do.

Comment: It really generates `{\mathrm e}` ??? That's weird you should probably fix that first.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Why is `{\mathrm e}`. Since the goal is to have upright `e` and not italic `e` which is the default. How should it be then? Thanks.... oh I see. I saw answer below now. I think You meant it should be `\mathrm{e}`. Ok, I will contact support there and let them know about this also. They have good support now for Latex, hopefully they will correct this also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your autogenerated code is bad, sorry. In

```
3\mathrm{ln}\left(x\right)
```

there are three atoms, namely

1. `3` of type Ord
2. `\mathrm{ln}` of type Ord
3. `\left(x\right)` of type Inner

Between two atoms of type Ord, TeX inserts no space.

To the contrary,

```
    3\ln\left(x\right)
```

contains again three atoms, but with a big difference, namely

1. `3` of type Ord
2. `\ln` of type Op
3. `\left(x\right)` of type Inner

TeX inserts a thin space (of the amount of `\thinmuskip`) between an Ord atom and an Op atom.

Sorry, but “garbage in, garbage out”. If the software is able to recognize the string `ln` to be set in upright type, it could well take the initiative of outputting `\ln` instead of the wrong `\mathrm{ln}`.

By the way, also `\left` and `\right` are out of place. And it's quite interesting that “e” is translated into `{\mathrm e}` instead of the more correct `\mathrm{e}` (if you *really* insist into printing the Euler constant upright).

A fix.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  

\mleftright

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewCommandCopy{\latexmathrm}{\mathrm}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\mathrm}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {e}{e}
    {i}{i}
    {ln}{\ln}
    {log}{\log}
    {sin}{\sin}
    % ... add to the list
   }
   { \latexmathrm{#1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
4 {\mathrm e}^{3 x}+3 \mathrm{ln}\left(x \right)
\]
                      
\[
4 e^{3 x}+3 \ln\left(x \right)
\]                                                                                                              
\end{document}
```

[image]

For LuaLaTeX and `unicode-math`, the workaround has to be different.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}  
\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmainfont{Baskervaldx}[
  UprightFont=*-Reg,
  ItalicFont=*-Ita,
  BoldFont=*-Bol,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BolIta,
]

\mleftright

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \NewCommandCopy{\latexmathrm}{\mathtextrm}
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\mathtextrm}{m}
   {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
     {
      {e}{e}
      {ln}{\ln}
      {log}{\log}
      {sin}{\sin}
      % ... add to the list
     }
     { \latexmathrm{#1} }
   }
 }% end of \AtBeginDocument
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
4 {\mathrm e}^{3 x}+3 \mathrm{ln}\left(x \right)
\]
                      
\[
4 e^{3 x}+3 \ln\left(x \right)
\]                                                                                                              
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `Baskervaldx.sty` is not the right choice when `fontspec` is used.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried to integrate the above into my main Latex file, I found conflict with the font I am using. When I add these 3 lines to the premable, with everything the same as you have, it gives latex error `\usepackage[mathit=sym,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}`. It is the font I am using now. But no big deal. I can not use this font for now. Just thought to let you know. Compiled with luatex, using most up to date TL 2020.

Comment: ... message is  `/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/baskervaldx/T1Baskervaldx-TLF.fd) (./foo3.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ly1/ly1ptm.fd)

! LaTeX Error: Command `\mathrm' not defined as a math alphabet.`

Comment: @Nasser If you don't show a full MWE, then one has to guess. Look at your MWE: is LY1 mentioned anywhere? Or Baskervaldx? And if you compile with LuaLaTeX, what are T1 and LY1 doing?

Comment: How is one supposed to know that using some font or some package will cause an issue with any solution posted? I try to make a MWE. If I post an example with every package I use and all the settings I have in my main Latex file, it will be 1000 lines long.  But any way. Thanks for you effort and time.

Comment: @Nasser I added the workaround for your case. Please, take care of providing the necessary information: you didn't mention LuaLaTeX and `unicode-math`, did you?

Comment: Thank you. I mentioned lualatex in my main question. `Compiled with lualatex, gives` I did not mention the font setting I happened to be using, because It never occured to me it could be relevant, as the many 10's of packages I use in my main build. But next time, I'll post the font I am using also in each MWE.

Comment: @Nasser If you compile with LuaLaTeX my first code you get exactly the same output. It's `unicode-math` that makes the **big** difference.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I like typesetting the Euler constant in Euler, or Computer Modern Upright Italic.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, `ln` is what’s called a log-like operator.

You can use either `\ln`, `\operatorname{ln}` or `\mathop{\mathrm{ln}}` to get spacing like `\log`.  You can also add `\nolimits` if you don’t like how subscripts and superscripts get placed above and below in display mode.

If `amsmath` did not already define it, you could write `\providecommand\ln{\operatorname{ln}}` and then have a `\ln` command you could use in your source, and be able to tweak in one easy-to-find place.